# Can non-monotonic activation function neural networks be trained in the same way as monotonic activation function neural networks?

Tags: neural-network

I have created a sigmoid based neural network that learns successfully using a backpropagation algorithm, with the error calculation (target-output) * output * (1-ouput). However I wanted to try different activation functions (scaled to output in the same range, 0 to 1). Logistic functions all seems to work fine, such as atan, tanh... but when i used a radial basis function, such as the guassian e^(x^2), the network just doesn't learn at all. Do I have to change the backprop algorithm when using gaussian activation functions, or other non-monotonic functions?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.** I just implemented a simple non-monotonic activation function in Torch, and it not only works, but it slightly outperforms Tanh on the [MNIST demo](https://github.com/torch/demos/blob/master/train-a-digit-classifier/train-on-mnist.lua) with the default settings (which uses SGD by the way.)

This is the activation function: 2x/(x<sup>2</sup>+1)

[image: 2x/(x<sup>2</sup>+1)]

... and here's the comparison for the first 10 epochs:

```
 Tanh  |  Other
-------|-------
89.34% | 92.87%
93.27% | 95.10%
94.81% | 94.91%
94.57% | 95.77%
94.41% | 96.06%
94.92% | 96.06%
95.02% | 96.27%
95.39% | 96.27%
95.41% | 96.27%
95.63% | 96.24%
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for an answer for this, theoretically the monotonicity does not make a difference and non-monotonic activation functions can still approximate any continuous function just as well. The problem therefore lies in the learning of the weights, which essentially means that you have to change your learning algorithm (backpropogation).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I assume you meant e^(-x^2) (you forgot the '-').
In the formula you mentioned, **output * (1-ouput)** is the derivative of the logistic function. If you want to use the Gaussian, the derivative becomes **- 2 * x * output**.